# Why no stock's amount data on us stock market?

Tags: equities, data

In chinese stock market , every stock's traded volume and amount (price * volume) data  was disclosed.

[image: source from sina finance]

Why in us stock market no amount data disclosed?

[image: source from yahoo finance]

There must be such 7 fields as `date`,`open`,`high`,`low`,`close`,`volume`,`amount` for every stock's EOD (end of day) data,no `adj close` in chinese stock data.

The amount in a trading day != close * volume, the chinese exchange (shanghai and shengzheng) sum every traded data into a total sum,
The amount in a trading day = sum(price * volume),they provide the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I go to barchart.com, I can get the volume-weighted average price (aka VWAP, under "+Study") added to any graph. The VWAP is just the notional (trade price*trade volume) divided by the total volume. Furthermore, the VWAP is more useful than the total notional traded.